# update ng-repeat values angularJS with php

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic-framework

In the code, there's ng-repeat, and I have to update "frais" of all values displayed by ng-repeat. this code update only last value. how can I do to update all, please?

file.html

```
<ion-content class="padding" ng-controller="FactureAdminCtrl" ng-repeat = "selectedName in selected">

<ion-list ng-repeat = "selectedName in selected">
          <div class="item item-divider center-text" name="codeE" ng-model="selectedName.CodeEnvoiColis"> {{selectedName.CodeEnvoiColis}} </div>  

          <label class="item item-input">
          <input width="20%" type="text" placeholder="Frais" ng-model="selectedName.FraisFact" style="color:#BA1B1B;"></div> 
          </label>
</ion-list>  

<a class="button button-info" href="#/factureAdmin" ng-click=updateFact(selectedName)> Submit </a>
```

app.js

```
$scope.updateFact = function(selectedName){ 

           $http.post(  
                "http://localhost/deb/updatFact.php",  
                { 

                'FraisFact':$scope.selectedName.FraisFact,
                'CodeEnvoiColis':$scope.selectedName.CodeEnvoiColis,
              }
           ).success(function(data){  
                alert(data);                                
           });  
    }
```

How can I do please!

Answer (score 1):

First of all don't put ng-repeat to this line,

```
<ion-content class="padding" ng-controller="FactureAdminCtrl" ng-repeat = "selectedName in selected">
```

remove it like this,

```
<ion-content class="padding" ng-controller="FactureAdminCtrl">
```

Then you have to send the full array to `updateFact` function,

```
<a class="button button-info" href="#/factureAdmin" ng-click=updateFact(selected)> Submit </a>
```

So the full array will be here in the function & you have to pass it to the backend & do whatever the thing you want & return data back.

```
$scope.updateFact = function(selected){ 

           $http.post(  
                "http://localhost/deb/updatFact.php",  
                //you have to pass the array here
           ).success(function(data){  
                alert(data);                                
           });  
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but I didn't understand which array you mean please !

Comment: `selected ` is an array right?? So you have to send this array to the backend & process

Comment: This is the function of selected : $rootScope.selected = [];
           $rootScope.namesF3 = [];
          $rootScope.exist = function(item){
            return $rootScope.selected.indexOf(item) > -1;
          }

          $rootScope.toggleSelection = function(item){
             var x = [];
            var idx = $rootScope.selected.indexOf(item);
            if(idx > -1){
                 $rootScope.selected.splice(idx, 1);
            }
             else{
                 $rootScope.selected.push(item);
             }

          }

Comment: how can I do please !